# The hidden landmines in a simple: df.A = sr

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

A simple operation like `df.A = sr` (assigning a `pandas.Series` to a column in a `pandas.DataFrame`) seems harmless, but it has many nuances. To someone like me starting to learn `pandas`, it brings many conveniences as well as bewilderment.

A simple example/challenge below, given:

```
df:
+----+-----+
|    |   A |
|----+-----|
|  0 |   0 |
|  1 |   0 |
|  2 |   0 |
|  3 |   0 |
|  4 |   0 |
+----+-----+

l = [777, 666, 555, 444, 333]

sr:
+----+-----+
|    |   0 |
|----+-----|
|  7 | 777 |
|  6 | 666 |
|  5 | 555 |
|  4 | 444 |
|  3 | 333 |
+----+-----+
```

what does `df` look like after `df.A = sr`?
or
what does `df` look like after `df.A = l`?

**With my current understanding, I broke down all implied operations in `df.A = sr`, and please correct/confirm/expand upon it:**
for example, I am not entirely sure of the correct terminologies.

```
# [0] a column in a DataFrame, is a Series, is a dictionary of index and values
# all cell to cell transfers are key-lookup based, individual element in an 
# index is called a "label" for a reason.

# [1] if sr didn't have some of the index labels in df.col's index, 
# the old values in those cells in df.col gets WIPED!
df.loc[ ~df.index.isin(sr.index)] = np.nan

# [2] values are transferred from sr cells into df cells with common index-labels. 
# As expected
df.loc[ df.index.isin(sr.index), 'A'] = 
    sr.loc[ [idx for idx in sr.index if idx in df.index] ]

# [3] sr's cells, whoes index-lables are not found in df.index, are ignored and 
# doesn't get to be assigned in df
sr.loc[ ~sr.index.isin(df.index)] # goes no where.

# [4] with all the wipping and ignore from above steps, 
# there is no error message or warnings.
# it can cause your mistakes to slip thru:
"""
df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['A'], index=np.arange(5))
df.loc[ df.index.isin( ['A', 'B']), 'A'] = sr
print(df)

df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['A'], index=[])
df.A = sr
print(df)
"""
```

**SPOILER. setups and results:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['A'], index=np.arange(5))
l = [777, 666, 555, 444, 333]
sr = pd.Series(l, index=[7, 6, 5, 4, 3])


RESULTS:
df.A = sr
df:
+----+-----+
|    |   A |
|----+-----|
|  0 | nan |
|  1 | nan |
|  2 | nan |
|  3 | 333 |
|  4 | 444 |
+----+-----+

df.A = l
df:
+----+-----+
|    |   A |
|----+-----|
|  0 | 777 |
|  1 | 666 |
|  2 | 555 |
|  3 | 444 |
|  4 | 333 |
+----+-----+
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question and answer site. It's okay to answer your own questions, but you should reformulate this as an actual question/answer pair (with the answer posted as an answer, not in the question), and the question needs to hold up even outside the context of you answering it yourself.

Comment: One comment I'll make that isn't an answer. A general tip that helped me is that you can assign almost any iterable to a dataframe column provided the dimensions are correct. That said, there is a ton of optimization under the hood, which allows dataframe operations to act intelligently with regards to indexing, as you've seen

Comment: And, one additional thing that helped me when I was learning: Try to use square brackets as much as possible rather than dot notation for df columns (`df['A']=` rather than `df.A=`). It's more explicit, self-documenting, and clearly delineates between attributes, methods, and indexing. Especially with one-letter column names, as `df.A` references a column named 'A', but `df.T` is shorthand for transposing your df.

Comment: @G.Anderson (and OP). It's not just that you should try to use square brackets to assign a column, you **should never** use the dot notation for assignment. You should get an warning when doing so with an array of the correct dimension. But to illustrate the danger, look at the output of the following: `df = pd.DataFrame({'foo': list('123')})` followed by `df.A = [6,7]`. Now assign the column `df['A'] = [7,8,9]` I bet you'll be surprised by the output of `df.A` at this point, or at least  we've broken the `.col_name` referencing.

Answer (score 2):

So the results you see is because of the following:

`sr = pd.Series(l, index=[7, 6, 5, 4, 3])`

You assigned the index values of l  specifically to [7, 6, 5, 4, 3].

When you do:

`df.A = sr`

The series **keeps** its index values. Then when you defined the df:

`df = pd.DataFrame(0, columns=['A'], index=np.arange(5))`

You ensured that the highest index value is 4 (`index=np.arange(5)`)

So your column output maitained the index vales of sr, and placed the values in A, thus only the index 3,4 value were shown.

When you did:

`df.A = l`

Your just assigning the values in l to the column A. So all the values will appear. If you changed `sr = pd.Series(l, index=[7, 6, 5, 4, 3])` to `sr = pd.Series(l)`, then set `df.A = sr`. You would end up with the exact same result as `df.A = l`.

Comment: interesting, I realized now that we all have our own ways of thinking. My amazement is mostly at the "wiping stuff in df to nan" or "ignored values in sr".